# Read, Find the string and then read the string

Tags: java, string

I would like to write a java program which reads a line, searches for a string in the line, and then reads the characters which are after the searched-for string.

For instance, say I read in the following line:

```
+version:20140825+extra_Name:session:13456@field.namer+xy_confirmation_value:IF_ui+XYZ_literal:next+ABC_meaning:next
```

I want to extract the string which is after `+ABC_meaning:`, which should return `next`.

Can I use `indexOf()` to accomplish this?

Comment: Spilt string by : then compare adjacent indexes, with the even index being the parameter and odd being the value in the array to get the value...

Comment: try this regex: .*\+ABC_meaning\:(.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question then yes, you could use [`String.indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [`String.substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) with something like

```
String str = "+version:20140825+extra_Name:session:13456@"
    + "field.namer+xy_confirmation_value:"
    + "IF_ui+XYZ_literal:next+ABC_meaning:next";
String toFind = "+ABC_meaning:";
int pos = str.indexOf(toFind);
String found = "";
if (pos != -1) {
    found = str.substring(pos + toFind.length());
}
System.out.println(found);
```

Output is the requested

```
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your string is `myString` then:

```
int position = myString,indexOf("+ABC_meaning:");
String out = myString.substring(position + "+ABC_meaning:".length);
```

`out` now contains "next"